# Lock Display Name To Nickname

Tags: admin, front-end, profiles

Using the following code to change the  author url links to their nickname. The issue is it seem to be conflicting and trying to use the display name instead. Can i lock the display name to the nickname or can i change this code up a bit. If i change the nickname from the wp-admin it changes with the nickname field just fine. However if users change the nickname from the front end form (using wp user frontend pro plugin) i have to go into wp-admin and set the display name to make it change.

```
      add_filter( 'request', 'wpse5742_request' );
           function wpse5742_request( $query_vars )
      {
      if ( array_key_exists( 'author_name', $query_vars ) ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $author_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT user_id FROM {$wpdb->usermeta} WHERE meta_key='nickname' AND meta_value = %s", $query_vars['author_name'] ) );
    if ( $author_id ) {
        $query_vars['author'] = $author_id;
        unset( $query_vars['author_name'] );    
    }
    }
     return $query_vars;
    }
     add_filter( 'author_link', 'wpse5742_author_link', 10, 3 );
     function wpse5742_author_link( $link, $author_id, $author_nicename )
    {
  $author_nickname = get_user_meta( $author_id, 'nickname', true );
     if ( $author_nickname ) {
    $link = str_replace( $author_nicename, sanitize_title($author_nickname), $link );
    }
    return $link;
    }
    add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', 'wpse5742_set_user_nicename_to_nickname', 10, 3 );
    function wpse5742_set_user_nicename_to_nickname( &$errors, $update, &$user )
    {
    if ( ! empty( $user->nickname ) ) {
    $user->user_nicename = sanitize_title( $user->nickname, $user->display_name );
   }
   }
```

Comment: It seems that whats going on is the profile links isnt being overwritten till you view the users profile in wp-admin then click save. you dont have to change anything just push save. But changing the info from front end changes the link but the page is a 404 till you click save in wp-admin... whats causing this?

Comment: i think it still could be an issue with display name. If i can get a snip to lace in functions.php that will always keep the display name the same has the nickname i think it will work. perhaps need somehting to trigger it though other than wp-admin profile save.

Comment: Or perhaps put a time on the script above to run like every 5min or so rather than on profile save? i think thats the issue.